# How to handle Doctrine relationships with Twig

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, twig

I have two entities, `Customers` and `Locations`. They are in a `ManyToOne` relationship (one customer can have multiple locations).

This is how I defined the relationship:

```
    class Customers { 
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45)
     */
    private $name; 
    }
```

And the entity `Locations`:

```
class Locations { 
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Customers", inversedBy="id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customers_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $customers_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=90)
 */
private $name;
}
```

I want to be able to click on a User and render in a Twig template all the locations associated to him. This is how I'm doing that now, but I'm not sure it's the proper way.
First the controller:

```
/**
* @Route("/showLocations/{id}", name = "show_locations")
* @Method("GET")
**/
public function showLocationsAction($id) {

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Locations');
    $locations = $repository->findBy(array('customer_id' => $id ));
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Customers');
    $customer = $repository->findOneById($id);

    if(!empty($locations)) {
    return $this->render("AppBundle:Default:showLocations.html.twig", array('locations' => $locations, 'customer' => $customer)); }

    else return new Response ("There are no locations to show");
}
```

This is the twig template:

```
<p>Locations associated with {{customer.name}}</p>
<table id="table_id" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Locations</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for locations in locations %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ locations.name|e }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine so far. But naming $customers_id should be $customer only.

Comment: Normally you would have a Customer::locations property with a one to many relation to Location.  That way, loading the customer will give the locations without any further effort.  Take a look at the product/category example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#relationship-mapping-metadata  In your case, customer is the category and location is the product.  And save yourself some future confusion, name your entities Customer instead of Customers and Location instead of Locations.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine so far. But naming for $customers_id should be $customer only since Doctrine will automatically fetch the related customer and hydrate it into an object.

Then you can fetch and display the customer with `{{ location.customer.name }}`

`$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AtlasBundle:Customers');
  $customer = $repository->findOneById($id);`

Can be omitted totally then.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean to call the Locations private property $customer_id as $customer?

Comment: Internally Twig will look for a public method named `::getCustomer()` on the Locations class and use that first: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html (See "Implementation" section)

Comment: Ok, it works except for the `{{ location.customer.name }}` part. I get this error `Key "customers" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist.` In the template, if I `dump` Locations, I can see that name for `Customers` is set to null.

Comment: I'm able to print the customer name with `{{ location.0.customer.name }}`. Is that right?

Comment: @Dygne: This looks like your mapping is not valid. It seems you get 2 customers per Location?

Comment: Yes, but the customer is always the same. I'm getting the Locations in the template, but I'm only able to access the customer name like I said, with `{{ location.0.customer.name }}`

Comment: This is clearly an error in the mapping then. Did you run `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` ?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine